# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ab' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, data-science

I am working on read and write file problem.
I do not think there is problem with the codes that read file, but I think there is some problem with code that write some decoded message on a file.
I got an error message saying:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20ab' in position 6: character maps to undefined>.
```

I have watched some videos that explain read and write file and imitated what the video explain. I think the line `output_file.write(decode(line))` is located wrong place. Where should I put it? Or if there are any other mistakes I made, Please let me know.
I wacthed some video that use `with open---as file:`, but this time I do not want to use it.

Here is my code:

```py
def decode(encoded_str):
    decoded_str = ''
    for char in encoded_str:
        decoded_str += chr(ord(char)-1)
    return decoded_str

print("Test:",decode('Hp Jsjti')) #print Go Irish
print('\n')


f=open('data/secret_message.txt','r')
output_file = open('data/secret_message_decoded.txt', 'w')

# read and process the file one line at a time 
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    print(decode(line))
    if line =='':
        break
    print(decode(line))
    output_file.write(decode(line))

f.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Please don't paraphrase your errors, [just show the full error as a copy-paste](/help/how-to-ask). Having said that, you're not telling Python to use `utf-8` encoding for your files, which is pretty important if you want to rule out possible reasons for getting unicode errors. But also: ask yourself what `chr(ord(char)-1)` does for each of those input letters. As a hint: that test print will _not_ print `Go Irish`, because `decode` does not exempt any letters. Every single letter in your input's getting changed (and if you _run your code_ this should be very obvious)